# Как запустить тест на Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Разбираюсь с новым Yii2, подтянул вот этот репозиторий:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2

Далее подтянул файлы с помощью composer в приложении **advanced**

Начал смотреть в сторону тестов, ранее никогда с ними не работал, вот и возникли трудности с пониманием этого дела.

Так у нас есть папки с тестами в следующих директориях: backend, common, console, frontend

Я новичок, поэтому сразу хочу начать с самого простого, поэтому будем пока работать с папкой **\frontend\tests**

Я уже установил у себя phpunit и хочу запустить первый тест для теста =).

Содержимое данной папки такое:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/apps/advanced/frontend/tests

Честно я почти ничего не понял, что у нас тут и зачем, скорее всего может разные фраэмворки тестов используются, но увидел знакомое название **unit** и полез туда.

НУ и дальше мои полномочия все. Тоесть подскажите пожалуйста как написать свой первый тест, что там как вообще происходит ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Пришло время обновить ответ. Оригинальную версию можно будет увидеть внизу.

---

##### Codeception

PHPUnit сам по себе никуда не делся, однако ни одно приложение не в состоянии выжить только за счет unit-тестов. Со временем появился [Codeception](http://codeception.com/), который представляет из себя большую надстройку над PHPUnit, [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) и еще кучи пакетов, в которые я сам не заглядывал. Codeception предоставляет три вида тестирования:

- Acceptance - "приемочное" тестирование, проверка работы пользователя с приложением на основе сценариев (BDD).
- Functional - функциональное тестирование, функциональная проверка работы приложения.
- Unit - модульное тестирование, низкоуровневое тестирование конкретных функций.

##### Unit testing

С модульным тестированием проще всего - это проверка конкретных функций: создаем массив данных из того, что должно поступить на вход и что должно получиться на выходе, потом прогоняем по этим данным функцию и смотрим, все ли получилось как хотели. Модульное тестирование не ограничивается только этим, но оно рассчитано именно на проверку отдельных функций, методов и модулей, точную сверку выходных данных с требуемыми, проверку состояний тех же модулей.

##### Functional testing

Функциональное тестирование появилось тогда, когда стало ясно, что кроме проверки функций необходимо проверять именно работу приложения - что оно не выдает 404 для существующих данных, выдает 403 для закрытых секций, выдает 400 на неправильно введенных данных. Функциональное тестирование постепенно развивалось - коды ответа кодами ответа, а разработчиков интересует именно получение пользователем той или иной информации на странице. Здесь и появилась такая штука, как selenium - сервер, который позволяет запускать браузер и взаимодействовать с ним, и webspider - эмуляция браузера, которая позволяет так же "ходить по страницам".

##### Acceptance testing

Codeception же несколько переформатировал понятие функционального тестирования и ввел acceptance testing. В codeception функциональное тестирование - это тестирование страниц через веб-спайдера, acceptance testing - тестирование страниц через браузер. Формально эти тесты могут совпадать с точностью до названия класса, но acceptance testing способен проверять реальную видимость html-элементов на странице и отслеживать работу javascript.

Yii первой версии существовал в отрыве от общих стандартов в пользу удобства использования (хотя, честно говоря, не знаю, были ли тогда стандарты). Yii 2 пришел и к неймспейсам, и к обильному использованию чужих пакетов, в том числе codeception. Codeception ставится так же, как и все остальные зависимости Yii - через [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

##### Как использовать codeception?

Codeception, как и большинство современных пакетов, предлагает работать с ним через командную строку. Основной исполняемый файл - `app_dir/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept`, 
для удобства я буду писать просто `codecept`. Проще всего установить codeception глобально и настроить команду-алиас на соответсвующий файл.

Сначала необходимо проинциализировать приложение:

```
codecept bootstrap
```

Это создаст папку tests и создаст внутри всю необходимую инфраструктуру. В примерах Yii это уже будет сделано.
После этого необходимо настроить codeception с помощью YAML-файлов в tests, но это лучше смотреть [сразу в документации](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/configuration).

Codeception предоставляет возможность писать тесты как на основе `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` (`CTestCase` из Yii 1.х был оберткой вокруг него), так и на основе своей обертки `\Codeception\TestCase\Test`. Создать тест проще всего опять же из консоли (предположим, что тест создается для модуля `HttpRequest`)

```
codecept generate:test unit HttpRequest
// Test was created in %app.root%/tests/unit/HttpRequestTest.php
```

Codeception сам добавляет суффикс `Test` (который позволяет отделять классы-тесты) и расширение `.php`.
Так как скорее всего тестов будет много, можно сразу указать папку, где должен валяться тест. Предположим, полное название `HttpRequest` на самом деле `\Core\Http\HttpRequest` и валяется он в папке `%app.root%/Core/Http`, тогда будет разумно поместить тест в папку `%app.root%/tests/Core/Http`:

```
codecept generate:test unit Core/Http/HttpRequest
// Test was created in %app.root%/tests/unit/Core/Http/HttpRequestTest.php
```

##### Прекрасно, а что мне теперь писать в этом файле?

Внутри файл находится класс теста. Этот класс представляет из себя набор методов-тестов, которые проверяют поведение кода, и дополнительных методов инфраструктуры.
Каждый метод-тест начинается с префикса `test` (наприме, `testValidate`; хорошим тоном будет подставлять название тестируемого метода после префикса, если в тесте проверяется только один метод). PHPUnit посканирует класс и обнаружит все методы, начинающиеся с этого префикса, а затем будет запускать один за другим. Каждый метод теста проверяет поведение кода, используя [assert-методы PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions), каждый такой метод проверяет полученные данные. Например, `$this->assertTrue($httpRequest->isPostRequest);` проверит, соответствует ли true значение `$httpRequest->isPostRequest`, и в случае, если проверка провалится, оборвет выполнение теста (т.е. только одного метода, если не используется `@depends`).
По поводу "инфраструктурных" методов: любое тестирование сталкивается с тем, что для тестирования требуется настроить окружение, загрузить какие-то данные, создать фальшивые объекты, создать массивы однотипных данных для проверки. Самыми главными здесь будут `_before()` и `_after()` (`setUp()` / `tearDown()` в PHPUnit) - они будут выполняться до и после выполнения каждого теста в классе, в них обычно выполняет подготовку фальшивого окружения/объектов.

Пример класса-теста:

```
<?php
use Codeception\Util\Stub;
use \Core\Http\HttpRequest;

class HttpRequestTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
    protected $codeGuy;
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST'; // в консоли, вероятнее всего, этого ключа изначально вообще не будет
    }
    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        unlink('dummy.html'); // стираемый созданный тестом файл
    }
    public function testIsPostRequest()
    {
         $request = new HttpRequest; // создаем тестируемый объект. В зависимости от характера теста, создание, возможно, будет разумнее вынести в _before()
         $this->assertTrue($request->isPostRequest); // выполняем непосредственно проверку поведения, сравнивая isPostRequest с true
    }
}
```

##### А как запустить написанное?

Как всегда - из командной строки. Следующая команда запустит все тесты:

```
codecept run
```

Т.к. часто придется обращаться к отдельному виду тестирования или вообще тесту (если отвалился единственный модуль, то толку-то все гонять?), то лучше запускать тесты по этому виду или вообще конкретный тест:

```
codecept run unit // все юнит-тесты
codecept run tests/unit/Core/Http/HttpRequestTest.php // конкретный тест, требуется относительный путь с суффиксом и расширением.
```

После этого codeception выведет количество тестов, проверок (один тест может включать в себя несколько проверок) и ошибок. Понятное дело, что любое количество ошибок, отличное от нуля, должно восприниматься как build: failed, и соответствующий код должен немедленно исправляться.

##### Эй, ты ничего не рассказал про остальные два вида тестирования!

Потому что сам в них толком пока не поварился (а еще мне лень). В принципе, [базовый getting started](http://codeception.com/quickstart) и любая IDE с подсветкой подскажут что к чему - они ОЧЕНЬ интуитивны.

---

(предыдущая версия текста про PHPUnit)

Модульные тесты (unit tests) в PHP в любом фреймворке всегда упираются в один и тот же пакет: phpunit. С чем бы вы не столкнулись, дело придется иметь именно с ним, возможно, в небольшой обертке.
Сама суть модульного тестирования заключается примерно в следующем: при разработке какого-то приложения после появления (или изменения) запланированного функционала этого приложения  параллельно с самим приложением пишется тестовое сопровождение. Тестовое сопровождение - это, как правило, набор классов, которые по наименованию и расположению повторяют тестируемое приложение, например:

> Приложение:
> models/ProductModel.php
> components/CrmService.php
>
> Тесты:
> tests/models/ProductModelTest.php
> tests/components/CrmServiceTest.php

(контроллеры тут пока специально не упомянуты)
Каждый класс - это набор тестов для соответствующего компонента, реально этот набор представлен методами внутри класса теста для этого компонента. PHPUnit автоматом запускает все методы класса, которые начинаются с test (и некоторые другие, но об этом в документации), поэтому типичный класс теста будет представлять собой примерно такую картину:

```
class ProductModelTest extends TestCase { // в данном случае TestCase - та самая обертка, которая будет наследоваться от PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    public function testGet() // негласная конвенция - называть метод по имени тестируемого метода
    {...} // проверка всевозможных комбинаций входных и выходных значений для метода ProductModel::get()
    public function testGetAll()
    {...}
    public function testValidation()
    {...}
}
```

Теперь непосредственно к yii2. Само приложение advanced представляет из себя просто скелет (точнее, я нашел в common один тест, но он не смог найти codeception), поэтому нам сначала надо будет написать какое-нибудь подобие модели, например, [такое](http://pastebin.com/zRDJCphU). В этой псевдомодели нужно оттестировать все методы, чтобы а) не забыть о недописанных в будущем б) быть уверенным, что в любых стрессовых ситуациях система поведет себя именно так, как надо и в) быть оповещенным ровно в тот момент, как что-то отвалится из-за переписывания низкоуровневых компонент. Соответственно, каждый метод (благо их здесь всего ничего) нужно нашпиговать всеми возможными приходящими значениями и убедиться в корректности отработки (точнее, шпиговать его каждый раз, как что-то поменялось). Я написал для этой модели небольшой и дурацкий тест ([ссылка](http://pastebin.com/4FcTEeqa)), который занимается ровно этим. Теперь можно проверить работоспособность всей этой конструкции, если модель закинуть в **common/models/ProductModel.php**, а тест в **common/tests/unit/models/ProductModelTest.php**. После этого в директории common/tests надо будет выполнить следующую комманду:

```
phpunit --bootstrap _bootstrap.php unit/models/ProductModelTest.php
```

Это запустит соответствующий тест (по умолчанию phpunit будет пытаться загрузить все файлы с названием *Test.php из текущей папки и подпапок; подробнее, как всегда, в доках) и даст примерно следующий вывод:

> PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> .......
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb
>
> OK (7 tests, 18 assertions)

Который говорит о том, что 7 тестов прошли успешно. Когда я писал модель, я в проверке на id вместо < 1 указал < 0, и в результате все невалидные айдишники прошли, о чем меня и уведомила тестовая проверка:

> PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> F......
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.00Mb
>
> There was 1 failure:
>
> 1)
> common\tests\unit\models\ProductModelTest::testGet
> Exception was expected for string input
>
> /srv/sandbox/yii2/apps/advanced/common/tests/unit/models/ProductModelTest.php:14
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 7, Assertions: 6,
> Failures: 1.

Такой вот сумбурный ответ.
Что касается остальных папок - это файлы для поддержки codeception (в папках с подчерком в начале названия), с которым я сам пока не разобрался (это тестирование более высокого уровня, включающее в себя phpunit), и файлы для различных видов тестирования. На самом деле PHPUnit годится только для библиотек, а для приложений является полумерой, пусть и довольно хорошо защищающей - в приложении должны работать не только модели, но и контроллеры, а для этого недостаточно сымитировать ситуацию - нужно поднять nginx/apache (а лучше оба) и убедиться, что на конкретные запросы приходят верные ответы. Это называется функциональным тестированием, до чего я сам пока не дошел, и осуществляется с помощью загадочной для меня (пока что) программы selenium. Папка functional, соответственно, отвечает за функциональное тестирование. acceptance, насколько понял - это папка для codeception-тестов, который идет еще дальше, и вместо простой проверки запросов/ответов эмулирует клики и отображение для пользователя. Все вместе это называется Continuous Integration (CI) и обеспечивает невозможность выложить в продакшен с некислой посещаемостью и функционалом какой-нибудь серьезный ляп. Я по выходным все пытаюсь развернуть себе полноценный сервер с поддержкой всего этого веселья, но реально в проектах мне пока хватало PHPUnit - остальное, конечно, полезно, но проекты не того масштаба )
В любом случае для ознакомления с тестированием придется сначала поработать только с PHPUnit, поэтому об остальном можно пока не задумываться.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Со всеми тестами уже разобрался, смог запустить прикинуть что там как. Теперь собственно буду приступать к написанию своего первого приложения через тестирование. Хочу попробовать сразу все это дело, начал читать книжку "Бек - Экстремальное программирование Разработка через тестирование", то без практики сами понимаете никуда!

Comment: Шикарный ответ.

Comment: ссылка на документацию не работает.

Comment: оффтоп: 10000 просмотров и так мало апов...

Comment: @Razzwan ну конечно. Все читают, разбираются в вопросе, а апвоутить то не царское дело.

Comment: ответ наверно снова устарел. пытаюсь запустить и не находит ни одного теста. можете подробнее написать7

Comment: @des1roer до выходных скорее всего нет

Comment: Небольшая поправочка. Selenium используется в acceptance тестах и позволяет тестировать через реальный браузер. Функциональные же запускаются через консоль.