# Как написать тест в YII2?

Tags: php, yii2, phpunit, codeception

Есть actionBooks который получает POST'ом данные о книге.

Нужно написать тест, который будет проверять, получил ли экшен данные, записалась ли книга в БД и возвращать ответ если нет.

Я уже развернул Сodeception через Сomposer. Интересует сам код, может у кого то есть конкретные примеры кода тестов, инфы очень мало, на оф сайте непонятно как что работает.

Comment: Гуглите по вашим тегам и будет вам счастье. http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#.V06yk5Nkj6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подготавливаете массив POST и проверяете.
Пример сохранения категории.

```
    public function testSaveCategory()
    {

    $category = new Category();

    //simulate form input
    $postTrue = [
        'Category' => [
            'title' => "sdgerg",
            'parent_id' => 8,
        ]
    ];


    //simulate form input
    $postFalse = [
        'Category' => [
            'title' => 6848,
            'parent_id' => 40,
        ]
    ];


    $this->assertTrue($category->load($postTrue));
    $this->assertTrue($category->save());

    $this->assertTrue($category->load($postFalse));
    $this->assertFalse($category->save());
}
```

Массивы можно вынести в отдельные свойства. Можно расширить проверки с помощью [assert методов](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html).

Также я поставил [codeaverage](http://allframeworks.ru/codeception/11-Codecoverage.html) (это не обязательно), чтобы проверять в процентном соотношении покрытие кода тестами.
Запускать вот так:

```
codecept run unit --coverage --html
```

Но это только модульное тестирование. Советую также прочитать [эту статью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301326/yii2-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-unit-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)